# Symfony 1.4 Doctrine Sluggable behaviors, strange behaivior! how to deal with foreign keys on save?

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine

```
A:
  columns:
    id: ...
    name: type ....
    b_id: type ... 
  actAs:
    Sluggable:
      unique: true
      fields: [name, b_id]
      canUpdate: true
  relations:
     B: { foreignAlias: As } 
B:
  columns:
    id : ...
    name: ...
```

Above the sort of schema =). It at least should give you the idea.
Desigred slug format "A.name-B.name"

I have written a csv importer where field A.slug is generated correctly( I haven't done anything to adjust it, all went by default ).

But I am facing issue when saving the record in the backend(symfony admin generator). It is generating the slug as A.name-B.id.
Q: What is the best way/direction to handle this case, so I have normal slugs without IDs

Answer (score 1):

I believe it works to define the relation as part of the sluggable, rather than the foreign key column, i.e.:

```
Sluggable:
  fields: [name, B]
```

Provided you have a `__toString()` method on B. If that doesn't work, or if you want more complex logic, you can use the builder option:

```
Sluggable:
  builder: [ATable, buildSlug]
```

You would then define in ATable:

```
public static function buildSlug($proposal, $instanceofA)
{
  return $instanceofA->name . '-' . $instanceofA->B->name; //do any other case altering, symbol removing here as well
}
```